# How does the Hoare partitioning works in QuickSort

Tags: python, quicksort

I've written the Python code of the algorithm of quicksort, but I don't quite know how it processes the array or the list.

What I know is the algorithm always takes the most left element as the pivot. Besides, I manually implement the algorithm, but I found something confusing. Here is the question:

1. It returns `j` if `i >= j`, what if `i < j` ? In this case, how do I know the return value? Is it `j`? Or other value should be returned?
2. How does it know if sorted?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
def quick_sort(arr, low, high):
if low < high:
    pivot = partition(arr, low, high)
    quick_sort(arr, low, pivot)
    quick_sort(arr, pivot + 1, high)
return arr

def partition(arr, low, high):
    pivot = arr[low]
    i = low - 1
    j = high + 1
    while (True):
        while (True):
            i = i + 1
            if (arr[i] >= pivot):
                break        
        while (True):
            j = j - 1
            if (arr[j] <= pivot):
                break       
        if (i >= j):
            return j

    swap(arr, i, j)




arr = [2, 4, 1, 6]
quick_sort(arr, 0, len(arr) - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time the pivot is returned from the `partition` function, which is `pivot = arr[low]`. For the first time, it returns the first element as a pivot.

After that, the algorithm separates it into two parts.

1. One is `quick_sort(arr, low, pivot)`, left part of the array.
2. Another is `quick_sort(arr, pivot + 1, high)`, right part of the array.

The right part of the array will be sent back to the recursion. Doing the `partition` again, and pass `arr[low] = pivot = 1` this time.

This algorithm ends when it passes the last "right" part of the array, which is only the element on the rightmost side, triggers the `if low < high` condition. When this condition doesn't meet, the algorithm returns the entire array.